# laravel 4 css files 404 not found

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-4

These are my folders:

```
app
--->views
------->css
----------->font-awesome.css
----------->index.css
------->layouts
----------->restaurants.blade.php
------->restaurants
----------->create.blade.php
```

in **restaurants.blade.php**
I tried this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('views/css/index.css') }}" />
        {{ HTML::style('views/css/font-awesome.css') }}
```

in both way, I got this exception:

`http://localhost:8082/ProjectName/public/views/css/index.css 404 (Not Found)`

`http://localhost:8082/ProjectName/public/views/css/font-awesome.css 404 file not found`

Could you help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assets are stored under your views, but you are linking to public.

Put the assets that you need to load (css, imgs, js) under public. Then you can simply

```
{{asset('css/style.css')}}
```

for example.

Also make sure your config/app.php document root is setup right, and if using apache, make sure that your vhost is setup properly to where /public/ is your Document Root.

Comment: The same error message but the url is `http://localhost:8082/ParkingProject/public/css/index.css 404 not found` so I guess that I need to put `view`

Comment: I can see the html, so the configuration is correct, right?

Comment: Did you relocate your css into public properly? It should not be in a view a folder. If you want asset('css/index.css') to work, the file should be located in /public/css/index.css

What are you using to host? php artisan serve?

Comment: when I moved the css folder to my public folder, it works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

For using laravel with Vite

```php
@vite("resources/css/app.css")
```